# Confusion regarding derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am new to calculus. This question may be silly. 
Suppose I have an equation
$$f_1(x)=f_2(x)$$
So we can differentiate both sides of this equation and write,
$$f'_1(x)=f'_2(x)$$
So why does the same approach work if $f_1(x)=x^2+3x+2$ and $f_2(x)=0$. This substitution will make the equation
$$x^2+3x+2=0$$ If we differentiate both $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ we would get $x=-3/2$ which does not satisfy the equation. Why is it so?

Comment: Remember that there are (at least) three different meanings of the "$=$"-sign.  The first meaning states that two objects are equal as in $1+1=2$ or in $x\cdot x=x^2$; the latter means that whatever values you substitute for $x$ will yield a true equation.  The next meaning regards definitions: $f(x):=x^2$.  Finally the third one deals with solving equations: In $x^2\overset{!}{=}25$ we search all soluting of the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only differentiate an equality like $f_1(x)=f_2(x)$ if it holds for every $x$.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't follow from the fact that $f_1(a)=f_2(a)$ that $f_1'(a)=f_2'(a)$. Your example is fine. A simpler one would be $f_1(x)=0$, $f_2(x)=x$, and $a=0$. We have $f_1(a)=f_2(a)=0$, but $f_1'(a)=0$ and $f_2'(a)=1$.